# Tkinter - how to display a 2d array of colors as an image?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

I am somewhat new to Python and completely new to Tkinter. I have the following python code:

```
class Level:

    def __init__(self, name, height, width):

        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.tiles = makeTiles(height, width)   

    class Tile:

        def __init__(self, x, y, type, color, isOccupied, enemy):

            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.type = type
            self.color = color
            self.isOccupied = isOccupied
            self.enemy = enemy

def makeLevel(name, height, width):

    level = Level(name, height, width)

    return level

def makeTiles(height, width):

    tiles = [[Level.Tile(x, y, "Surface", "red", False, "None") for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]

    return tiles

test1 = makeLevel("test", 10, 10)

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        if x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "black"
        elif x % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "blue"
        elif y % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "yellow"

colorMatrix = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        colorMatrix[x][y] = test1.tiles[x][y].color

print(colorMatrix)
```

which generates the following 2d array of colors:

```
[['black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red'], ['black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red'], ['black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red'], ['black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red'], ['black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue', 'black', 'blue'], ['yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red', 'yellow', 'red']]
```

Which I would like to represent in tkinter with each array item being a 25 pixel by 25 pixel cell of the given color, and all of the cells flowing seamlessly together with no visible borders or gaps - it should look something like this:

[Image of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0F3R.png)

The only solutions I've been able to find involve text fields, not colors. Is there any way to do this in tkinter, or do I need to use a more complex GUI framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could do it by creating corresponding rectangles arranged in a grid on a `tkinter.Canvas` object. Besides being relatively simple, you can make it so individual `Tile`s can be selected, if you wish.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk  # assume Python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk  # nope, Python 2

class Level:
    def __init__(self, name, height, width):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.tiles = makeTiles(height, width)

    class Tile:
        def __init__(self, x, y, type, color, isOccupied, enemy):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
            self.type = type
            self.color = color
            self.isOccupied = isOccupied
            self.enemy = enemy

def makeLevel(name, height, width):
    level = Level(name, height, width)
    return level

def makeTiles(height, width):
    tiles = [[Level.Tile(x, y, "Surface", "red", False, "None") for x in range(width)] for y in range(height)]
    return tiles

test1 = makeLevel("test", 10, 10)
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        if x % 2 == 0 and y % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "black"
        elif x % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "blue"
        elif y % 2 == 0:
            test1.tiles[x][y].color = "yellow"

colorMatrix = [[0 for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        colorMatrix[x][y] = test1.tiles[x][y].color

#print(colorMatrix)

width, height = 400, 400

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("colorMatrix")

frame = tk.Frame()
frame.pack()

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, width=width, height=height)
rows, cols = len(colorMatrix), len(colorMatrix[0])

rect_width, rect_height = width // rows, height // cols
for y, row in enumerate(colorMatrix):
    for x, color in enumerate(row):
        x0, y0 = x * rect_width, y * rect_height
        x1, y1 = x0 + rect_width-1, y0 + rect_height-1
        canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, width=0)
canvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Display:

[image: screenshot of output from script]